# How can I have my Windows keymap on Mac?

Tags: windows, mac, keymap

On Mac, to get a "{" for example, you have to press OPTION key plus 8 to get a curly brace. But on Windows it is ALT-GR plus 7.

Another example: On Windows I can press CTRL and Backspace to remove one whole word. On Mac it is OPTION + Backspace.

Is there a way I can remap these Mac-driven behavior to be more Windows-like? Because this is, as a very long Windows user, a big burden on me to have such a different keyboard layout.

Edit: I'm using a german keyboard layout.

Comment: What keyboard layouts are you using, both in Windows and OS X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele) to create your own keyboard layout. However, I think there is no way to differentiate between left and right (ALT-GR) alt keys. This should make brackets and curly braces more accessible.

Regarding Ctrl-BS and Alt-BS, I don't think there's a way to change that.

Answer (score 1):

For something more geeky: [hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/Site/KeyBindings/Windows%20Bindings.dict](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/Site/KeyBindings/Windows%20Bindings.dict) (from the article [Cocoa Text System](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/Site/Cocoa%20Text%20System.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Weird, on both my mac and my PC, SHIFT+[ gives a {. Must be some weird European keyboard layout? In both OS's there are settings to change your keyboard layout, but you just get to pick between the built in settings. To change keys one by one, you might be able to use AutoHotKey.

Comment: Hi! Sorry, I forgot to add that I'm using a german keyboard layout. So seems like for the US keyboards everything remains the same.

Well... not over here :( Our @ sign, {, } etc. are all on different key-combinations.

Answer (score 0):

In System Preferences -> Keyboard & Mouse -> Modifier Keys, you can change the mapping for your caps lock, control, alt/option, and command keys.  You could use this to swap control and alt/option.

It's not a panacea, but it might help.